# Invoke gradle task depending on scripts result

Tags: jenkins, gradle, parameter-passing

I'm trying to invoke specific gradle task depending on the actual device's soft version.
My idea was to check soft version, store gradle task name in variable and then invoke it:

Execute shell:

if[ $(./checkSoftVer) -eq XX ]; then
VAR="testVerXX"

elif[ $(./checkSoftVer) -eq YY ]; then
VAR="testVerYY"

fi

Invoke gradle script:

Tasks: $VAR

It's not working, I was looking for a different solution, but didn't find one. Do you have any advices/ideas? Thanks

Comment: What does it mean _not working_?

Comment: Instead of "gradle testVerXX" it's executing "gradle $VAR"

Comment: Don't you have to define `VAR` before the while if-elif block? AFAIR this is how it works in bash.

Comment: I've tried, same result. Gradle's task is just passing given string.

Comment: Only idea I have is to use conditional statements, but there would be a lot of conditions, I'd rather avoid that.